# APPCMD is create empty file

Tags: iis, appcmd

We have issue with executing APPCMD and it produces empty file.

When we try with below command

AppCmd list AppPools > c:\test\test.txt

It creates a empty file.

But when we just list in cmd prompt like below is works

AppCmd list AppPools

We have opened cmd prompt as administrator as well

Am I missing anything??

Answer (score 0):

We have uninstalled all the IIS components and reinstalled in Windows 2012 R2 and it is working now

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.